# Ondrej repo on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apache-httpd, nginx, php7

I'm following a [guide](https://tecadmin.net/install-php-7-on-ubuntu/) for loading PHP 7.4 on Ubuntu 18.04 from the Ondrej Surý repo and noticed the CAVEAT about `apache2` and `nginx` from the

```
1. If you are using php-gearman, you need to add ppa:ondrej/pkg-gearman
2. If you are using apache2, you are advised to add ppa:ondrej/apache2
3. If you are using nginx, you are advised to add ppa:ondrej/nginx-mainline
   or ppa:ondrej/nginx
```

I have apache serving content, but Nginx as a reverse proxy in front of apache. Would I just pick #2?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the first repository `ppa:ondrej/pkg-gearman` which provide `php7.4` because it is not available on bionic.

You can add [`ppa:ondrej/apache2`](https://launchpad.net/%7Eondrej/+archive/ubuntu/apache2) which provide `apache2` package and [`ppa:ondrej/nginx`](https://launchpad.net/%7Eondrej/+archive/ubuntu/nginx) providing `nginx` package (available on Bionic)